# Utility functions for directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I want to make an angular directive that generates links to resources that look like this:

```
<a href="http://link/to/resource/1234">link/to/resource/1234</a>
```

from an object that looks like:

```
resource = {
  id: 1234,
  otherProperty: 'foo'
}
```

How can I do this effectively w/ a directive? Ie, I'd like to not have to repeat the part that goes `'/link/to/resource/{{id}}'`. I can't seem to get that to work right. One of the several things I've tried:

```
app.directive('myResource', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      resource: '='
    },
    baseUrl: 'link/to/{{resource.id}}',
    template: '<a href="http://{{baseUrl}}">{{baseUrl}}</a>'
  };
});
```

which ends up rendering:

```
<a href="http://" class="ng-binding"></a>
```

Other things I've tried (like making `baseUrl` a function/sticking it in `scope`) have resulted in similar things/errors.

Is there a way to get something like this to work?

Comment: what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this is to use the directive's link function to set the variable up for you, like this:

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.baseUrl= 'link/to/'+scope.resource.id;
},
template: '<a href="http://{{baseUrl}}">{{baseUrl}}</a>'
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4s3F/)

Alternatively you could use this approach:

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.baseUrl= 'link/to/';
},
  template: '<a href="http://{{baseUrl}}{{resource.id}}">{{baseUrl}}{{resource.id}}</a>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek5bW/)

Comment: I would have preferred something that still lets me used the `{{}}` style angular templates, as the actual resource url is somewhat more complicated, but this works I suppose.

Comment: @alecb I added an alternative approach, see if it's closer to what you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

just write a directive controller

```
app.directive('myResource', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      resource: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.getBaseUrl = function(resource){
         return 'link/to/'+resource.Id;
      };
    },
    template: '<a ng-href="http://{{getBaseUrl(resource)}}">{{getBaseUrl(resource)}}</a>'
  };
});
```

a function makes more sense,because you wont have manage resource state change.You may answer that the Id is unlikely to change but in my opinion,it's better practice in general.

http://plnkr.co/edit/I2QKNB1o8jvZf7kCDT2v?p=preview

Comment: This seems to result in a circular dependency for me error for me.

Comment: there is no reason why it would be : check this out : http://plnkr.co/edit/I2QKNB1o8jvZf7kCDT2v?p=preview

Comment: One tradeoff to keep in mind with using functions inside a binding is performance.  That function will be called every `$digest` cycle.  Besides the inherent overhead in a function call Angular is able to optimize variable lookups in `$digest` making them quite a bit more performant than functions in bindings (and the eventual use of object.observe() may further this difference).  Of course, performance is only one of many tradeoffs to consider.